# Tried C on Macbook Air M2 in VS code, changed settings for code runner to show output in terminal, now its ruined?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I was following a tutorial on youtube https://youtu.be/pdfLW9PSrhQ , I got to the step to change settings for code runner to show the output for my code, I clicked the setting, run it, then lines start spitting ou, so I then choose Run C/C++, and now I get nothing but endless lines of info when I try to run a C program, even my python programs are screwed up, quitting VS code didn't help.

Edit: Apologies for the pictures, this is the code I wrote into VS

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    char fname[20], lname[20];
    scanf("%s",fname);

    printf("Enter your first name : ");
    scanf("%s",fname);

    printf("Now your last name : ");
    scanf("%s",lname);

    printf("Your full name is %s %s\n",fname,lname);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the exact prompt I receive when I run code now.

(base) sierrasmac@MacBook-Air HOME? % cd "/Users/sierrasmac/Desktop/MyVSCode/" && gcc whatever.c -o whatever && "/Users/sierrasma
c/Desktop/MyVSCode/"whatever

When I run it after this prompt, I receive this back

cd "/Users/sierrasmac/Desktop/MyVSCode/" && gcc whatever.c -o whatever && "/Users/sierrasmac/Desktop/MyVSCode/"whatever
Enter your first name : Now your last name : Your full name is "/Users/sierrasmac/Desktop/MyVSCode/" &&
zsh: abort      "/Users/sierrasmac/Desktop/MyVSCode/"whatever
(base) sierrasmac@MacBook-Air MyVSCode %

Comment: You started your project in a folder on your desktop. Make a new folder in your home folder for that purpose and create new projects there.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 1):

The settings for running your program are stored in the JSON file .vscode/launch.json. You can show the output on VS Code's integrated terminal by adding the entry `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to `configurations`. The default is `"internalConsole"`, which is the Debug Console (if you open this tab it is probably where your program's output is right now.)

Comment: I found the launch.json file and pasted "console": "intergratedTerminal" into the configurations part. I was told to replace the colon with a comma and did, now it says, Incorrect type. Expected "object". I don't know if I'm in the right place, or if I might need to just scrap everything a redo the Mac terminal process. I apologize for being a little bit slow at this. Still learning the basics. Thank you so much for your help!